# Powerpoint Reusing Objects

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create a ppt with lots of pictures and audios, which will be reused many times. For example, I will have a chime that will play on each slide load. I don't want the same image or audio to be loaded over and over again because I will be hosting this on my website and I need to minimize bandwidth and cpu of my web host.

If I copy and paste an audio or image on a master slide, is it duplicating the actual object or is it duplicating the reference to the object?

Comment: The object is just a reference. You are duplicating the object and therefore the reference

Comment: Unless it's specifically INSERTED as an object, it's not an object per se, so @EricF may or may not be correct. But insert an image onto one slide, then copy it to other slides and you'll only have one instance of the image in the PPT/PPTX file.  I'm not sure if the same is true for audio, but it's easily enough tested:  Insert a large audio file. Save the PPT. Note the size.  Open it, copy the audio file to several other slides, save to a new file, note the size.  If it's grown by only a slight amount, then the same is true of audio as  of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add images/sounds to a PowerPoint presentation via Insert, Picture or Insert, Audio, the image or sound file is embedded in the PPTX (though sounds may be linked in 2007 and prior).

When you copy/paste one of these inserted images and sounds from slide to slide, PowerPoint creates a pointer to the original embedded image/sound; it doesn't duplicate the data.

You can test verify this by checking to see whether the size of a PPTX file increases as you copy sounds/images from one slide to another.

You can also "crack" the zip file, look in the ppt\media folder and verify that there's only one instance of each added sound/image.

The same is NOT true when you use Insert | Object | From File to insert external files as Objects.  Each time you insert a file as object or copy an already inserted object to another slide, the PPTX file grows by the size of the embedded object.

In general, for this and other reasons, it's bad practice to insert anything as an object if PowerPoint can natively insert it as sound/picture/video/etc. unless you have a specific reason for wanting an object instead of regular PPT content.